Maxent Variable Selection R Package
I'm currently using the Maxent Variable Selection package in R, but I'm encountering an error:
Error in file(file, "rt"): cannot open the connection
Additionally: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt"):
cannot open the file 'C:/maxent/outputtest/maxentResults.csv': No such file or directory

I'm new to R and I understand that this typically means the files can't be found. I've double-checked my working directory and the file paths to ensure they are correct, but the issue persists. I've looked through various forums but haven't found much relevant advice. Any suggestions on how you managed to get this package working would be greatly appreciated!
my code is below:

`library(raster)
library(dismo)
library(rJava)
library(MaxentVariableSelection)

#set bioclim variables
bio1<-raster("bio1.asc")
bio2<-raster("bio2.asc")
bio3<-raster("bio3.asc")
bio4<-raster("bio4.asc")
bio5<-raster("bio5.asc")
bio6<-raster("bio6.asc")
bio7<-raster("bio7.asc")
bio8<-raster("bio8.asc")
bio9<-raster("bio9.asc")
bio10<-raster("bio10.asc")
bio11<-raster("bio11.asc")
bio12<-raster("bio12.asc")
bio13<-raster("bio13.asc")
bio14<-raster("bio14.asc")
bio15<-raster("bio15.asc")
bio16<-raster("bio16.asc")
bio17<-raster("bio17.asc")
bio18<-raster("bio18.asc")
bio19<-raster("bio19.asc")
cec<-raster("cec.asc")
cfvo<-raster("cfvo.asc")
elev<-raster("elev.asc")
nitrogen<-raster("nitrogen.asc")
ocs<-raster("ocs.asc")
ph<-raster("ph.asc")
Q2<-raster("Q2.asc")
sand<-raster("sand.asc")
silt<-raster("silt.asc")
water<-raster("water.asc")

#set no data values to zero

bio1[bio1==0]<-NA
bio2[bio2==0]<-NA
bio3[bio3==0]<-NA
bio4[bio4==0]<-NA
bio5[bio5==0]<-NA
bio6[bio6==0]<-NA
bio7[bio7==0]<-NA
bio8[bio8==0]<-NA
bio9[bio9==0]<-NA
bio10[bio10==0]<-NA
bio11[bio11==0]<-NA
bio12[bio12==0]<-NA
bio13[bio13==0]<-NA
bio14[bio14==0]<-NA
bio15[bio15==0]<-NA
bio16[bio16==0]<-NA
bio17[bio17==0]<-NA
bio18[bio18==0]<-NA
bio19[bio19==0]<-NA
cec[cec==0]<-NA
cfvo[cfvo==0]<-NA
elev[elev==0]<-NA
nitrogen[nitrogen==0]<-NA
ocs[ocs==0]<-NA
ph[ph==0]<-NA
Q2[Q2==0]<-NA
sand[sand==0]<-NA
silt[silt==0]<-NA
water[water==0]<-NA
#make bioclimate variables a stack
env<-stack(bio1,bio2,bio3,bio4,bio5,bio6,bio7,bio8,bio9,bio10,bio11,bio12,bio13,bio14,bio15,bio16,bio17,bio18,bio19,cec,cfvo,elev,nitrogen,ocs,ph,Q2,sand,silt,water)

#read occurrence data
occdata<-read.csv("occurrencelocations.csv")
occ_data<- occdata[,c("longitude","latitude")]

#extract bioclim variables in each occurrences
bioclim_values<- extract(env,occ_data)
data<-data.frame(bioclim_values)

#set background points
bg_locations<-randomPoints(env,1000)
bg_bio_clim<-extract(env,bg_locations)
#changing variables with MaxentVariableSelection
occ_full<-cbind(occ_data,bioclim_values)
write.csv(occ_full,"C:/maxent/occ_full.csv",row.names = FALSE)
bg_full<-cbind(bg_locations,bg_bio_clim)
write.csv(bg_full,"C:/maxent/bg_full.csv",row.names = FALSE)

MaxentVariableSelection::VariableSelection(maxent="C:/maxent/maxent.jar",
                                           outdir="C:/maxent/outputtest",
                                           gridfolder="C:/maxent",
                                           occurrencelocations="C:/maxent/occ_full.csv",
                                           backgroundlocations="C:/maxent/bg_full.csv",
                                           additionalargs="additionalargs",
                                           contributionthreshold=5,
                                           correlationthreshold=0.7,
                                           betamultiplier=seq(2,6,0.5))`


Looking at the documentation at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MaxentVariableSelection/MaxentVariableSelection.pdf
on pages 9-10 there is an example of the MaxentVariableSelection::VariableSelection()
VariableSelection(
maxent="C:/.../maxent.jar",
outdir="OutputDirectory",
gridfolder="BioORACLEVariables",
occurrencelocations=system.file("extdata", "Occurrencedata.csv", package="MaxentVariableSelection"),
backgroundlocations=system.file("extdata", "Backgrounddata.csv", package="MaxentVariableSelection"),
additionalargs="nolinear noquadratic noproduct nothreshold noautofeature",
contributionthreshold=5,
correlationthreshold=0.9,
betamultiplier=seq(2,6,0.5)
)

Only the maxent= attribute has the drive letter.  the rest of the attributes do not have a drive letter (folder name only). In the code you pasted, the c: drive letter is in the folder names. This might be why you get the error message.
